# FFmpeg audio not work on mobile devices

Tags: ffmpeg

i'm using code audio in ffmpeg but work on pc but not work on mobile, on mobile audio mute
Please tell me fix it, thank you

```
-af "pan=stereo|c0<c0+0*c1|c1<c0+0*c1,aeval=val(1)|-val(1),volume=1.5" -vcodec libx264 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100
```

Comment: Please always provide the full, actual `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output. Also, I'm not sure what exactly you're tying to do. Why are you duplicating the left channel into the output left and right channels? Why include `+0*c1`? Seems unnecessary.

Comment: Code here @LordNeckbeard i test it but on mobile video muted not audio
ffmpeg -i ga.mp4 -af "pan=stereo|c0<c0+0*c1|c1<c0+0*c1,aeval=val(0)|-val(1),volume=1.5" -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast 8.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Possibly phase cancellation. You duplicated the input left audio channel into the left and right channels of the output, then inverted the phase of the right channel. Your mobile may be downmixing to mono, resulting in phase cancellation, therefore resulting in no audio.

This is just speculation because you did not provide much info.

Comment: Code here @LordNeckbeard: i test it but on mobile video muted not audio
ffmpeg -i ga.mp4 -af "pan=stereo|c0<c0+0*c1|c1<c0+0*c1,aeval=val(0)|-val(1),volume=1.5" -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast 8.mp4